# Java Reflection (unsure on how to word this, look inside for more info)

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I need to make a Deep Copy of a 2D array. I know how to do this

```
int[][] a = new int[original.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    a[i] = Arrays.copyOf(original[i], original[i].length);
}
```

However, I'm now in a position where I don't know the Object type of the Array I'm copying. I have a method like so

```
public Object[] copy(Object[] original) {}
```

Which should return a deep copy of original IF it is an array of arrays. If the method is given a int[][], I can't cast that to an Object for the array (since it's a primitive type).

Currently, I can check to see if 'original' is a 2D array like so

```
if(original==null||original.length==0||!original.getClass().getName().startsWith("[")) {
    return null;
}
```

But now I'm unsure on how to do a Deep copy of an array of an unknown type. I assume I'll be needing to use Java Reflection, although I'm not 100% sure on how I would go about this.

For reference, this was my original attempt

```
public Object[] copy(Object[] original) {
    if(original==null||original.length==0||!original[0]getClass().getName().startsWith("[")) {
        return null;
    }
    Object[][] returnArray = new Object[original.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
        returnArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf((Object[]) original[i], ((Object[]) original[i]).length);
    }
    return returnArray
}
```

Unfortunately, int[] cannot be casted to Object[] (or any primitive[]).

Comment: Don't your method work for any type?

Comment: @YassinHajaj My original attempt was to simply try to cast each time I did a copy. Primitive types cannot be casted to Objects.

Comment: In my opinion, over-head of converting CustomObjectType from Object , is the job of CustomObjectService where ever it is. (You must know reflection is expensive!) . Consider passing a parameter of java.lang.Class (CustomObjectType.class) **or** take the parameter as Object<T> (generics) and return it after casting it by type T

Comment: @SrinathGanesh This is HW, so I am unable to modify the method parameters.

Comment: @Storm The real problem is the method you've been tasked to implement is a poor design. For example, if the type of the objects in the array are `enum` instances, you're hosed, as they can not be copied. Consider finding a better course/teacher.

Comment: Ok so with reflection you cast it , forget it for now . what do you want to return ? int/Integer float/Float or Object ..... ( You cannot over load method with return type )

Answer (score 1):

I could think of a solution with a switch for the primitives, like Arrays has a copyOf-function for every primitive:

```
public static Object[] copyDeep(Object[] original) {
    Object[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length);
    if ( newArray.getClass().getComponentType().isArray()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length ; i++) {
            switch (newArray[i].getClass().getComponentType().getSimpleName()) {

            case "int" : newArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf( (int[])newArray[i],Array.getLength(newArray[i]));
                break;

            case "float" : newArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf( (float[])newArray[i],Array.getLength(newArray[i]));
                break;
            // TODO other primitives

            default: newArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf( (Object[])newArray[i],Array.getLength(newArray[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

`